# How can I use Singleton DI for Microsoft DistributedRedisCache?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-core, redis

My question is simple but I am wondering how to use singeleton DI for Microsoft Distributed Redis Cache? When I check our startup.cs . I realized that something wrong. What do you thing of it?

```py
 services.AddSingleton<IConnectionMultiplexer>(ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(Configuration.GetConnectionString(ProjectConst.Config.AzureRedisCacheConnection)));
            var redisConnString = Configuration.GetConnectionString(ProjectConst.Config.AzureRedisCacheConnection);
            services.AddDistributedRedisCache(options =>
                {
                    options.Configuration = redisConnString;
                    options.InstanceName = "Test";
                });
```

I think that below code is enough for distributed cach . I guess "AddDistributedRedisCache" is not useful not necessary for cache.

```
 services.AddSingleton<IConnectionMultiplexer>(ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(Configuration.GetConnectionString(ProjectConst.Config.AzureRedisCacheConnection)));
```

This one is enough for Distribution ? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: The question isn't really clear. `AddSingleton<IConnectionMultiplexer>` has nothing to do with caching and `IConnectionMultiplexer` isn't part of ASP.NET Core. Without `AddDistributedRedisCache` you don't have caching at all, much less distributed, or using Redis.

Comment: Where does `IConnectionMultiplexer` come from? The first result when googling for this is the StackExchange.Redis repo. Is the real question how to use a Redis client instead of adding caching to ASP.NET Core?

Comment: services.AddSingleton<IConnectionMultiplexer>(ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(Configuration.GetConnectionString(ProjectConst.Config.AzureRedisCacheConnection)));
 IS ENOUGH for CACHE?

Comment: *NO*, it has *NOTHING* to do with caching. Don't shout. *If* you use StackExchange.Redis, that line creates a singleton Redis connection. It doesn't add caching to your application. You won't be able to use the [Distributed caching interfaces and tag helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-3.0) in your code. You'll have to hard-code Redis calls,timeout checks etc in your controllers or build your own abstraction that mimics the caching interfaces

Comment: ASP.NET Core *Caching* can store its data in any number of providers - files, relational databases, key/value stores, distributed memory caches like memcached or systems like Redis. `AddDistributedMemoryCache` enables caching using a simplified distributed memory cache. `AddDistributedRedisCache` does the same using Redis as the storage. `AddDistributedSqlServerCache` does the same using a database, possibly with in-memory tables. Others have created other implementations, eg for NCache. *All* of them enable the same caching middleware, API and behavior